# Essential difference between Microsoft Bot Node JS SDK and Rest client

Tags: node.js, rest, bots, botframework

This is not a programming question but a very basic fundamental question faced by many. Microsoft Bot Framework provides NodeJS and Rest Client. I want to understand what is the significance of the SDK. Usually Rest apis are built on Nodejs. Thus what makes Node SDK different from Rest API client?

Answer (score 1):

They don't provide a REST client, they provide a REST API that you, by creating a client, can consume. If you are `Node.js` dev, you will go with the SDK because is a powerful, easy-to-use framework that provides a familiar way for `Node.js` developers to write bots. You can use it to build a wide variety of conversational user interfaces, from simple prompts to free-form conversations.

The REST API's are there to allow devs to create a bot with any programming language, even if there isn't an SDK for it.

You should review the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-builder-overview-getstarted